# Optaplanner VRP Edge_weight_section

Tags: optaplanner, graphhopper

Using optaplanner I have started solving VRP's however all my distances are extremely high, in the range of 33000 km, I have been using graphhopper API to determine edge weights for my locations.

When testing the Belgium data given in optaplanner however, the edge weights given by graphhopper differ completely from that used in the EDGE_WEIGHT_SECTION in the .vrp files

Comment: Please note that the weights that are returned from the GraphHopper Directions API are not the distances. They are more proportional to the time but can also be different due to other priorities. So you should consider using all three variables (weight, distance and time) for your VRP cost function

Answer (score 0):

The Belgium datasets where generated by [this code](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/vrp-dataset-generator/blob/master/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/extension/vrpdatasetgenerator/FromCsvLocationsToVrpGenerator.java) a few years ago. That code uses GraphHopper too. The road-km datasets should give you about the same distance numbers between any 2 locations as you generate yourself, if you use the same locations set. If that's not the case, give a clear example of how they differ.

Do note that updated openstreetmaps files will lead to slight km distance changes, as new roads (=shortcuts) become available.